# JavaScript Input Elements

Tags: javascript, html, e-commerce, shopify

I am having a issue with my Script that is responsible for changing the text within the buttons.

It appears that the script is finding the first element with "id=add-to-cart" and then changes its value.  Is there a way to have it find the respective input element?

Here's the code below

```
<form id="add-item-{{ product.variants.first.id }}" method="post" action="/cart/add" >
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ product.variants.first.id }}" />


{% unless product.available %}
        <span><input type="submit" name="add" id="add-to-cart" value="{{ settings.tr_sold_out }}" class="cart disabled" disabled="disabled" /></span>
      {% else %}
        <span><input type="submit" name="add" id="add-to-cart" value="{{ settings.tr_add_to_cart }}" class="cart" /></span>
      {% endunless %}
```

Also, here are a couple of images offering a more visual explanation.

[1st Image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ixj5sx7jd8hhye8/screenshot1.png?dl=0)

"Add to Cart" works for every item (adds to shopping cart)

[2nd Image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9mkh5w0olkwtmq6/screenshot2.png?dl=0)

When the "Add to Cart" button is selected on another item (say below the first item, shown in the image) it will add the product to the cart but only the top button will display "Added" or "Sold out" state.

Also, just to mention my store is based on the Shopify platform, so there are some specifics with the displayed code related to a theme.

If I did a poor job describing what I am trying to achieve please let me know and I will try to explain better.

Thank you!

Comment: `id`s should be unique

Comment: you have not provided any script?

Answer (score 0):

HTML id's **must be unique** in a document.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id

Your ids are duplicate. It stops at the first one it finds (which isn't even a predictable browser behavior, others might do the last, or even one of the ones in the middle).

In general, avoid using IDs, but if you have to, find a way to make them be unique.

Comment: So, I discovered that {{ product.variants.first.id }} actually generates the unique "id" for the product.  It works for <form id="add-item-{{ product.variants.first.id }} which adds the specific product to the cart.  Is there a way to add this to "add-to-cart" id?